# Cannot grab the correct information from JOINed tables

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

**What the app should do**

The app is a quiz app, multiple choice 4 possible answers (only 1 is correct), with a number of difficulty levels and a number of question categories.

I have a table with questions, a table with answers, and a table with the difficulty levels, which I co-developed with someone who I am no longer in contact with (he did the SQL and database work, which is why I'm struggling).
There are several quiz modes, but for this issue let's concentrate on the 'standard' quiz modes (eg Easy, Medium, Hard, which loads questions based on the difficulty level, and works perfectly) and the 'custom' mode (for which one, or multiple, categories are selected by the user before the quiz starts, which doesn't work).

The WORKING code for getting answers for the standard quiz mode is below - again, this works:

```
                cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                    String.format(
                            "SELECT a.%s %s, question_id, a.text text, is_correct " +
                                    "FROM %s a JOIN %s q ON a.question_id = q.%s " +
                                    "JOIN %s l ON q.level_id = l.%s WHERE l.level = ? AND q.is_active = 1",
                            BaseColumns._ID, BaseColumns._ID,
                            ANSWERS_TABLE_NAME, QUESTIONS_TABLE_NAME, BaseColumns._ID,
                            LEVELS_TABLE_NAME, BaseColumns._ID
                    ),
                    new String[]{Integer.toString(level)}
```

**My Problem**

Below is the code for getting answers for the custom quiz mode. Let's say the user picks quiz categories 'History' and 'Technology' (or even just one of those categories). When I run this particular query, the quiz loads up fine, but no answers are displayed:

```
        cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                String.format(
                        "SELECT a.%s %s, question_id, a.text text, is_correct " +
                                "FROM %s a JOIN %s q ON a.question_id = q.%s WHERE q.category = ? AND q.is_active = 1 ",
                        BaseColumns._ID, BaseColumns._ID,
                        ANSWERS_TABLE_NAME, QUESTIONS_TABLE_NAME, BaseColumns._ID
                ),
                new String[]{thisQuestionCategory});
```

**Further info**

I'm happy to post up any information on the database or app (tables, column names, Java code etc please just ask - I didn't want to dump it all here immediately).

**Database/Table Info**

As requested, some info on the tables:

[image: List of tables]

[image: Once item from the questions table]

[image: One item from the answers table]

**Finally**

I understand that the rest of my code could be flawed causing this issue, but the SQL query seems like the best place to start, as it's my least familiar area. I've been through the logic of the rest of the code and found no issues, but if we cannot uncover any issue with the SQL, I can post Java code so you can see how the application comes together. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Despite this question's length, it presents almost nothing on which we could base an answer.  You need to pare this down to a [mcve], noting well that that probably does not mean choosing verbatim excerpts from your actual program (follow the link for more information).  If the problem is that the query you highlight returns no results, then we will want to see the actual query text and some example data for the tables involved, and probably not much else.

Comment: The query text is already in the question, in the form of a rawQuery from my Java code. I'm perfectly happy to provide further info on tables. Let me grab some of the table data and post it up.

Comment: The query **text** is *not* in the question.

Comment: OK, if you don't mean the query itself, then I clearly misunderstand you, and after a search online am still unsure what text you are looking for. As for minimal code, there are only two SQL queries in my question, and I cannot make the code complete and runnable as it would require a database, as well as the Java code from the application. All I wanted at this stage from the question, is for someone to take a look at the SQL queries and let me know if they look valid, and so I've added a screenshot of my tables to help.

Comment: I mean the query itself.  As text.

Comment: I can only provide what I have already - the query as it appears contained in the Java code is all I have. Like I say in the question, the SQL and DB stuff was setup by someone else I no longer have contact with, which is why I am so stuck, despite trying to learn what I can.  Is the code inside the rawQuery example above not a valid SQL query?

Comment: I think you're stonewalling, but if you really cannot obtain the query text, then you need more help than we are prepared to provide in this medium.  In that case, I recommend engaging a consultant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173344/discussion-between-mike-83-and-john-bollinger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following example tables :-

[image]

[image]

- Note the **id** columns have been named **_id** to reflect the value that `Base.Columns._ID` resolves to (i.e. _id not id as per your screen shots).

And that your SQL will resolve to (assuming that the category passed via thisQuestionCategory is **HISTORY**) :-

```
SELECT a._id _id, question_id, a.text text, is_correct 
FROM quiz_answers a
JOIN quiz_questions q ON a.question_id = q._id 
WHERE q.category = 'HISTORY' AND q.is_active = 1
;
```

Then the result would be :-

[image]

i.e. functionally there appears to be nothing wrong with the code.

You could add something like the following :-

```
Log.d("CURSORINFO",String.valueOf(cursor.getCount())+ " rows were extracted.");
```

and then run and check the log to see how many rows were being extracted.

- If the number is greater than 0 then your issue is elsewhere (later).
- If the number is 0 then, try removing the where clause (e.g. code as below) and rerunning. If you still retrieve 0 rows then in all likelihood there is no joined data. i.e. for an answer to be included it must reference a question.

  ```
      cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
          String.format(
                  "SELECT a.%s %s, question_id, a.text text, is_correct " +
                          "FROM %s a JOIN %s q ON a.question_id = q.%s",
                  BaseColumns._ID, BaseColumns._ID,
                  ANSWERS_TABLE_NAME, QUESTIONS_TABLE_NAME, BaseColumns._ID
          ), null);
  ```

Comment: Thanks a million MikeT, this is really helpful, now I have plenty to go off

Comment: Using the accepted answer to gather info, along with 'DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor);' to view what data the cursor held, I sorted the issue. The 'selected category' from the app started with an uppercase letter, but the DB category was all lower case, and thus everything was being filtered out in the query results.